# Sharepoint 2016 REST API - get list ID & file ID from direct file link

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I have the full SharePoint URL for a file, like: `https://my-sharepoint-host.net/subsite/library/LOOONG folder name that exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value/fileName.txt`

I need to obtain some details about that file: the listId and the fileID, so that I can then reach it with a link like `https://my-sharepoint-host.net/_api/Web/Lists(guid'xxxxx-xx-xxxx')/Items(xx)/File` .

But the original URL is **too long**, and I cannot used it in a */_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(...* HTTP Request.
If I try this, I get the message `The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.` from SharePoint.

What options do I have ?

What URL can I call to get those id field for the file ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have  you tried reading the file from PowerShell?  That should at least get you the GUID for the file:

Requires [SharePoint PnP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps)

```
$site_url = "https://my-sharepoint-host.net/subsite/library/"
Connect-PnPOnline  -Url $site_url -UseWebLogin
$Items = (Get-PnPListItem -List $list_name  -PageSize 2500).FieldValues    
foreach($Item in $Items)
{
  # echo out the file meta data, look for the document GUID
  $Item.FileLeafRef
}
```

Comment: I don't have that option, I don't have access to powershell.
I need to implement functionality for a tool which does HTTP requests...

Comment: There are third party tools that will do this.  If you google "check for broken links in sharepoint libraries", you will find them.